# Why Python stops using GPU and switches to CPU in runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, cpu

I have been using this:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
```

in order to run on GPU. It has been working properly since today.

The problem now is that, in the middle of the runtime, my program stops using GPU and switches to CPU, so it becomes too slow.

Any idea on why is that happening?

Output at the beggining of the execution for nvidia-smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.67       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970     On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8    14W / 200W |    363MiB /  4039MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla K40c          On   | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| 35%   74C    P0   136W / 235W |  11011MiB / 11441MiB |     94%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1037      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            20MiB |
|    0      1150      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          12MiB |
|    0      7430      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           166MiB |
|    0      7560      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         158MiB |
|    1     13772      C   python3                                    10998MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And then, when it begins to run too slowly:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.67       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970     On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8    14W / 200W |    363MiB /  4039MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla K40c          On   | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| 35%   69C    P0    63W / 235W |  11011MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1037      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            20MiB |
|    0      1150      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          12MiB |
|    0      7430      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           166MiB |
|    0      7560      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         158MiB |
|    1     13772      C   python3                                    10998MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post the terminal outputs of `nvcc -V `and `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: What does `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` give you?